# Linear Algebra - Linear transformation is inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

So I have this matrix

$$M = \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1&7&9&3\\
      2&15&19&8\\
      7&52&66&27\\
      3&4&10&-24\\
      \end{array}
      \right] $$

and I need to show that the linear transformation is inconsistent. 
So basically

$$  M \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      x\\
      y\\
      z\\
      t\\
      \end{array}
      \right] $$

$$ = \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      a\\
      b\\
      c\\
      d\\
      \end{array}
      \right] $$

that means it's inconsistent

this is the reduced form.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1&0&2&0\\
      0&1&1&0\\
      0&0&0&1\\
      0&0&0&0\\
      \end{array}
      \right] $$

So how do I show that the linear transformation is inconsistent. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does it mean to say that a linear transformation is "inconsistent"?  What is the definition?

Comment: Well it the book, it says Let M be an m x n matrix and if m < n, then for each vector b in R^m that linear system Ax=b is either inconsistent or has infinitely many solution.

Comment: That is what's meant by a **linear system** being inconsistent but you are asking about a **linear transformation** being inconsistent.

Comment: "Show that the linear transformation Tm: R^4 -> R ^4 by multiplication of column vectors on the left by M is not surjective by exhibiting a column vector not in the image." Thats from the question, So if M[x,y,z,t] = [a.b,c,d] then it inconsistent

Comment: No ... If $M[x,y,z,t]=[a,b,c,d]$ *has no solutions*, then it is inconsistent.

Comment: yeah thats what I meant, but how do you solve it or show that it is inconsistent.

Comment: You're going to need the RREF (or a REF) of $M = \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&7&9&3&a\\
      2&15&19&8&b\\
      7&52&66&27&c\\
      3&4&10&-24&d\\
      \end{array}\right]$

Comment: Well I have the RREF which is the last matrix in the question above. What do I do with that to prove its inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

Reducing $M\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\\t\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\end{array}\right]$ we get $\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&7&9&3&a\\
      2&15&19&8&b\\
      7&52&66&27&c\\
      3&4&10&-24&d\\
\end{array}\right]$
$\rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&7&9&3&a\\
      0&1&1&2&b-2a\\
      0&3&3&6&c-7a\\
      0&-17&-17&-33&d-3a\\
\end{array}\right]$
$\rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&7&9&3&a\\
      0&1&1&2&b-2a\\
      0&0&0&0&c-a-3b\\
      0&0&0&1&d-37a+17b\\
\end{array}\right]
$.

This is consistent only if $c-a-3b=0$. If we pick any vector where this doesn't hold, e.g. $\left[\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1\\0\end{array}\right]$, then that vector is not in the image of left-multiplication by $M$, which (as per your comment) is what your question actually asked you to show.